# Error referring to enum imported from npm types

Tags: typescript, npm

I recently added typings to a private npm module.

One of the module's exported type is the following enum:

```
export enum ServerResponseCode {
  LoginFailed: 'loginFailed',
  LoginExpired: 'loginExpired'
}
```

Then it is imported by another typescript project and used as following:

```
import { ServerResponseCode } from 'private-module'

if(response.code === ServerResponseCode.LoginExpired)
```

This code does not raise any compilation errors, but on runtime I get an error: 'Cannot read property LoginExpired of undefined'

Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to simply export a [const enum](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html#const-enums) in the type declaration file of private-module:

```
export const enum ServerResponseCode {
  LoginFailed: 'loginFailed',
  LoginExpired: 'loginExpired'
}
```

Short explanation from this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159049/4610489):

The enum is defined as `const` so that any reference to its elements are inlined (by ts compiler), this way avoid a run time lookup to the `ServerResponseCode` object which is actually `undefined` (because .d.ts files do not result in any JS).

Comment: For future readers, please be aware of the downside of exporting const enums: https://ncjamieson.com/dont-export-const-enums/